# Can WMP use cover.jpg/folder.jpg?

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-player, album-art

I'd like Windows Media Player to automatically use covers present in music folders, labeled `cover.jpg` or `folder.jpg`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Media Player uses `folder.jpg` for picking up cover art

> here's no need at all to create the
>   small art.  WMP will create it from
>   your Folder.jpg.

( reference: [Microsoft Technet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itpromedia/thread/10c4467e-fe22-4faa-bbbb-c8a91aba333c) )

Answer (score 1):

Read further: Microsoft consider folder.jpg a reserved file.  And if you use images better than 200x200, MS will resize them without telling or asking you.  That doesn't hurt WMP, but it may be annoying if you don't want to be tied to MS.

You should probably prefer to use cover.jpg.  Apparently WMP will pick these up when indexing your collection.

Hearsay only.  I don't use Windows; I've just been trying to work out what the de-facto standard filename is.